# Use different (non-English) web-service for CKEditor spellchecker

Tags: internationalization, ckeditor, spell-checking

I find the webspellchecker.net as a very useful tool, but unfortunately webspellchecker.net doesn't offer one for my language. I have recently found a spell checker for my language (Cuzco Quechua) that I can connect to it through a webservice.

Now I need to find a way to integrate it with the CKEditor. So How can I do this? Is there a plugin that allows me to to do something similar?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: My language is Cuzco Quechua, it is spoken in southern of Peru.